# Probability One of the three carries the number 5, and the other two numbers Smaller?

Tags: probability

> 10 people playing social games. Each participant has a number 1-10. 3 players randomly selected. What is the probability
>   One of the three carries the number 5, and the other two numbers Smaller?

I thought about it this way:
$$\frac{\binom{10}{1}*\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}$$
The answer in the book:
$$\frac{\binom{1}{1}*\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}$$

Why did they not choose the person with the number 5 and take it he must be selected?

Thank you!

Comment: Please reproduce questions exactly, don't paraphrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator in the answer key counts the number of ways of selecting the one person who holds the card with the number $5$ and two of the four people with cards with numbers less than $5$.

There is only one card with a $5$ on it, so we must select the only person with that card.  The number of ways of doing that is $\binom{1}{1}$.

We must also select two of the four people with cards with numbers less than $5$, which can be done in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.

Hence, the number of ways of selecting one person with the card with the number $5$ and two other people with numbers less than $5$ is $$\binom{1}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

*Only one man has the number 5:*
$$\frac{1\cdot\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}}$$

Comment: But what are the chances he's even choose (there are many others)?

Comment: Each person has already received number. And then "3 players randomly selected"

Answer (score 0):

The favorable combos would be of the type $(5,4,3) , (5,4,2), (5,4,1), (5,3,2) .....$

We aren't interested in **who has what**, only in the combos of $3$ numbers, thus

$Pr = \frac{\binom11\binom42}{\binom{10}{3}}$